# Would reverse thrust increase with a decrease in aircraft forward speed when referring to propeller reverse thrust?

Tags: thrust-reverser

Would reverse thrust in a propeller increase with a decrease in aircraft forward speed?

Answer (score 2):

If the propeller keeps the pitch constant while in reverse thrust,  the component of the relative wind perpendicular to the prop disk goes down with decreasing aircraft speed. Hence, the AoA also goes down, the lift produced by the blade decreases, and the reverse thrust does also decrease...

Comment: That assumes that the engine RPM is also constant. Reducing the load will usually increase the RPM, and higher RPM *could* produce more power. So "it depends"